# Getting error while using arcore_flutter_plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, arcore

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
  The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
  root project 'android' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

here is my app/build.gradle
plugins

```
{id "com.android.application"id "kotlin-android"id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"}
```

```
def localProperties = new Properties()def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->localProperties.load(reader)}}
```

```
def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')if (flutterVersionCode == null) {flutterVersionCode = '1'}
```

```
def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')if (flutterVersionName == null) {flutterVersionName = '1.0'}
```

```
android {namespace "com.example.world_map"compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersionndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
```

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.world_map"
    // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
    // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

}

```
flutter {source '../..'}
```

```
dependencies {implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.37.0'
```

```
// Provides ArFragment, and other UX resources.
implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.17.1'

// Alternatively, use ArSceneView without the UX dependency.
implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform:core:1.17.1'
```

}

Here is my android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'repositories {google()mavenCentral()}
```

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

}

```
allprojects {repositories {google()mavenCentral()}}
```

```
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'subprojects {project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"}subprojects {project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')}
```

```
tasks.register("clean", Delete) {delete rootProject.buildDir}
```

I tried many things. I changed the kotlin version but error is not solving.